# Jquery dialog afterOpen event

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to use a [jquery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/%20%22jquery%20dialog) as a "please wait" message.  This usually works but this particular task is CPU intensive and freezes prior to the async dialog open.  I have tried attaching the task to the "open" event in dialog but the open event and "focus" event fire prior to the dialog opening

```
$("#dialogbox").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    modal:true,
    title: "Use of Open event",
    width:300,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('hello open');
    },
     focus: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('hello focus');
    }
});

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    $('#dialogbox').html('<h2>Watch this</h2>An alert box should have opened');
    $('#dialogbox').dialog('open');
});
```

[fiddle me](http://jsfiddle.net/6adapotz/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: try opening it from ajaxStart event https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: You can try using setInterval to delay whatever you want to do in the open event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout(fn, 0);` to requeue the execution. As you can see in the example "hello focus" appears before "hello open".

```js
$("#dialogbox").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    modal:true,
    title: "Use of Open event",
    width:300,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        setTimeout(function(){alert('hello open');}, 0);
    },
     focus: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('hello focus');
    }
});

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    $('#dialogbox').html('<h2>Watch this</h2>An alert box should have opened');
    $('#dialogbox').dialog('open');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialogbox"></div>
<input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Click Me">
```

Comment: can you explain better how this works?  what is requeueing the execution?

Comment: @LrakWortep just a delay was applied to the the display of the alert using [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) you can read more on it.

Comment: @mcv wouldnt you need a > 0 time as the second param for setTimeout, having it set to 0 means no delay.

Comment: @LrakWortep, that is correct. It was provided as an example. If you run it and compare to yours even with that 0, that is enough time difference to allow the `dialogbox` you want to appear just before or in this case the same time as your `open()`